# What materials could be used instead of cement for a water-tight trench

Tags: waterproofing, pool

I'm trying to create a water obstacle to walk horses through - maybe even deep enough for them to swim through.

I'm having trouble coming up with an idea for what to use to keep water in and have good footing (without mud) at the same time, but something that's a lot easier on the pocket-book than cement.

Any suggestions for what I should use for the walls and the floor? they can be different if necessary. I figure since sailing ships and canoes were created long before concrete, I should be able to make something that holds water. I could probably even spray on a water-proof liner that has traction for the footing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that cement (or, rather, concrete) in and of itself isn't going to hold water. It's still have to be waterproofed.

I don't know the dimensions or schematics, but my first thought would be a pond liner (basically, giant rubber sheets) and then topped with sand or other material to provide the traction.

I think a bigger issue might be to figure out how to maintain it, though. I imagine this water could get pretty nasty after a while without some form of filtration system.

Comment: Also, if horses are walking through it, I'd give it a few days at most before a hoof punctures the liner...

Comment: hence the sand...I'm thinking you'd need quite a bit (not unlike the 'natural sand' swimming pools). But yea, I don't know the whole physics of horses and water hazards so it may still be an issue.